# Require structure with array of hash maps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm using Ruby on Rails 7 to build a REST API that accepts a payload via HTTP PATCH that looks like this:

```json
{
  "answers": [
    {"question_id": 1, "content": "My answer content ONE"},
    {"question_id": 2, "content": "My answer content TWO"}
  ]
}
```

I want to validate the structure of this response in my controller using strong parameters.

I've tried a bunch of similar SO posts but none of them seem to work for me.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```rb
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(answers: [{question_id: 1, content: 'some answer'}])

params.require(answers: [:question_id, :content])
# I get: `require': param is missing or the value is empty: {:answers=>[:question_id, :content]} (ActionController::ParameterMissing) 

params.require(:answers).require([:question_id, :content])
# I get: NoMethodError on the second .require

params.require(answers: [[:question_id, :content]])
# I get: param is missing or the value is empty: {:answers=>[[:question_id, :content]]}
```

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer but if you want to validate params, especially for an API, I have found Rails native infrastructure a bit limiting in this capacity (and a bit too tightly bound in my opinion). Instead I would recommend looking into libraries like `grape` if you need a full API infrastructure or `dry-validation` if you just want to validate the params. Both assimilate nicely into a rails application and in my experience this creates better decoupling and makes testing far simpler in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution just after I posted the question.

The solution which worked is:

```rb
def answer_params
  params.require(:answer).each do |answer_param|
    answer_param.require(%i[question_id, answer])
  end
end
```

This allows me to ensure that all values are provided in the correct structure and use it in my controller method like this:

```rb
def update
  answer_params.each do |answer_param|
    puts answer_param['question_id']
    puts answer_param['answer']
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why insist on validating the params only through `ActionController::Parameters`? I have always found limitations with the params API for nested structures (to be specific more deep structures for API I have built) like you have and in such cases I always validate the data in the most basic manner. For e.g. for the data structure you have shown I would validate it in following manner:

```
def validate_answers_data
  received_answers_arr = params[:answers]

  if received_answers_arr.blank?
    # return error requires answers not received
    return
  end

  whitelisted_answers_data = []

  received_answers_arr.each do |h|
    question_id = h[:question_id]
    answer_content = h[:content]

    if question_id.present? && answer_content.present?
      whitelisted_answers_data << { question_id: question_id, content: answer_content }
    end
  end

  if whitelisted_answers_data.blank?
    # return error answers data received found invalid
    return
  end


  whitelisted_answers_data
end
```

Params API is definitely useful for whitelisting data but when it poses limitations for a particular data structure, then instead of trying to insist on implementing the validation through only that API, it is better to implement through pure Ruby constructs which is the option always open.

Hope you find this suggestion helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I did find a solution which I shared as a separate answer because it's totally different from this one. Appreciate the response though and you have my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the method to ensure params structure like below:

```
def answer_params
 params.permit(answers: %i[question_id content])
end
```

and then use this method in your `update` action like:

```
def update
  answer_params[:answers].each do |answer_param|
    puts answer_param['question_id']
    puts answer_param['answer']
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I'm correct this will only prevent additional values being provided? It won't ensure the right values are provided?

Comment: this should ensure no additional keys are provided apart from `question_id ` and `content` inside the `answers` array.

Comment: apologies I should have been clearer but I was asking specifically regarding `require` so it will raise an error if fields are missing.